# A dot product between a vector and a tensor

Tags: vector-analysis

I'd like to understand how to write $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u}$ in open form, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the two dimensional velocity vector, and $\nabla$ is the gradient operator. I'd be glad if you could help me with this.
Regards

Comment: What is "open form"? For example, would $u_i\partial_i u_j\vec{e}_j$ useful to you?

Comment: I'd prefer vector form and not the index notation. Thank you for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is intended as an inner product between $\mathbf{u}$ and the operator $\nabla$:
$$
\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla=\sum_{i=1}^2u_i\partial_i=u_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+u_2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}
$$
applied to each component of the following vector field, in the present case again the vector $\mathbf{u}.$

So we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2u_i\partial_iu_j=\sum_{i=1}^2u_i\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}
$$
or more explicitly, with $\mathbf{u}=(u,v)$
$$
(uu_x+vu_y,uv_x+vv_y)
$$

Comment: Yes, this gives the answer. However this is the index notation, and I'd like to calculate solve it using vector calculus.
Thank you very much for your answer by the way!!!

Comment: @charlietan84 You already have the vector notation in your question, there is nothing more than that

Comment: in vector notation if I first calculate $\nabla\mathbf{u}$ and then I apply the dotproduct, this gives me the wrong answer. Or I can't do that? I mean I can't apply the dot product between a vector and a tensor? You see I'm very bad on this. Is there any book out there that you can recommend me? A really basic one? Regards

Comment: the notation in your question means $(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{u},$ you should do the inner product first

Comment: I see...Any resource that you could recommend so that I could learn this?